Basic question about integration by parts formula
Following Evans in the appendix, he says that if $u,v \in C^1(\overline{B_1})$ where $B_1$ is an open ball, then
$$\int_{B_1} u_{x_i}v\ dx = -\int_{B_1} u v_{x_i}\,dx+\int_{\partial B_1} uv\nu^{i}\,dS $$
So, if we consider $u$ identically $1$ and $v \in C_0^{\infty}(B_1)$ we arive at
$$\int_{B_1}v_{x_i}\,dx = 0$$
Is this true? I don't think the integral of every partial of a $C_0^{\infty}(B_1)$ function is zero... what I'm doing wrong?

Yes, exactly that is true. If a function on a line is zero at both ends, then it must go down as much as it goes up, See also fundamental theorem of calculus.
